# Norton Security gets installed by itself

Tags: windows, security, anti-virus

I never installed any Norton product on my Windows 10 PC. But suddenly I found Norton security installed and Windows defender (Windows security) deactvated.
I uninstalled the Norton Security with their removal tool. But the next day I found it has installed itself.
I had run Malwarebyte and found no problems.
My questions are:

1. Why does it happen?
2. How can I prevent it for keeping on installing (it is downloading the files repeatedly?).
3. How can I block the symantec site from accessing my computer.
   Please someone help.
   Thanks.

Comment: Contact Norton Support and get the Full Removal app for the specific version you have and do a complete uninstall. Before restarting, run Microsoft SysInternals, Autoruns.  Run Autoruns and look for Norton trying to start from your computer preload. Stop that, and the restart and test.

Comment: Is this system connected to an AD domain by chance?

Comment: What is AD domain? I connect to internet through a personal WiFi.

Comment: It cannot be installing itself if it was truly removed. Either the removal tool is incorrect, or some other installed program is doing it.

Comment: Norton is packaged with other installers, and Norton doesn't install itself automatically, as you appear to assume happened. What other software have you installed lately, particularly around the time Norton appeared? Is this a new computer? What brand? Does your brand have a Helper program that installed Norton?

Comment: I have not installed any programs when I noticed the problem. Removed Norton with their removal tool. Checked with MAlwarebyte and removed any suspects. Reactivated Microsoft security. But next day (today) I found that Norton Security is installed and Microsoft Security (Windows defender) is disabled. Mine is a locally assembled computer and OS, apps are installed manually. The Norton problem is a very recent one - 4 days back.

Comment: What did Autoruns find?

Comment: Autoruns finds several Norton entries since I have not uninstalled it. (e.g., Norton Security Shell Extension Module (Verified) Symantec Corporation c:\program files\norton security\norton security\engine\22.14.0.54\navshext.dll 04-04-2018 07:08) I am afraid that it will get installed again if I just remove it without finding the problem.

Comment: It is included on many installers.  If you OK through the setup it will install.  It has happened to me.  New computer + installations means Norton snuck in the front door!

Comment: That seems to be the case. But how do I get rid of it and prevent it from sneaking back in?